# Как поправить условия

Tags: php

Подскажите как правильно подправить условия? сейчас при заходе на страницу браузер выдает ошибку HTTP ERROR 500

```
if (count($this->forecast)>0) { foreach ($this->forecast as $date=>$daypart) :

    echo $date

    foreach ($daypart as $dp=>$data) :

        echo str_pad($dp,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo $data['symb'];
        echo $data['t']['min'];
        echo $data['t']['max'];

    if (($data['p']['min']) > 0) :

    echo "Давление" .round($data['p']['min']*0.75006375541921). "мм. рт. ст.";

    endif;

    endforeach;

    endforeach; 

    }  else { 

    echo "В данный момент информация о погоде отсутствует";

}
```

Comment: 500 ошибка не из-за вашего кода, ознакомьтесь когда она вызывается

Comment: поподробнее пожалуйста, не совсем понял "ознакомьтесь когда она вызывается"

Comment: 500 ошибка происходит со стороны сервера, так вот мой совет, чтобы вы разобрались когда она вызывается, проверили свои коннекты и посмотрели логи nginx/apach

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context в строке if (count($this->forecast) > 0) {

Comment: вот мой полный файл https://dropmefiles.com/cv4Q2

Comment: что у вас находится в переменной $this->forecast?

Comment: @Eugene Nagornichyh https://dropmefiles.com/cv4Q2 вот

Comment: Что за dropmefiles? Вы предлагаете эти ваши файлы скачивать? Добавьте всю необходимую информацию в вопрос, текстом.

Comment: Почему вы используете $this? Это метод класса? Не статический метод?

Answer (score -1):

На строке 57-58 вы используете $this внутри исполняемого файла (не метода из класса), по логике вещей вы должны выполнить функцию, получить результаты и дальше уже парсить, но парсинг там немного некорректный т.к. город и данные по нему лежат на одном уровне вложенности. Нужно чтобы массив выглядел таким образом

```
'data' => [
    'city' => ['data_about_weather'],
    'city_2' =>  ['data_about_weather'],
]
```

А вообще советую вам почитать что такое функциональное программирование и что такое ООП. И в чем разница. Вы сейчас пытаетесь смешать функциональщину и ООП.

Прикладываю весь код:

```
<?php

function getForecastXML($cid='579432') {
    $cid = "579432";
    $hoffset = "4";
    $appid= "d86ad74d22ce9cc528d8baee65acd408";
    $lang= "ru";
    $days = array();
    $xml = @file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=$cid&mode=xml&appid=$appid&lang=$lang&type=like");
    if ($xml===false) { return;} else {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $cityname = (string)$xml->location->name;
        $weekdays[0] = "Воскресенье";
        $weekdays[1] = "Понедельник";
        $weekdays[2] = "Вторник";
        $weekdays[3] = "Среда";
        $weekdays[4] = "Четверг";
        $weekdays[5] = "Пятница";
        $weekdays[6] = "Суббота";

        if (count($xml->forecast->time)>0){
            foreach ($xml->forecast->time as $fpart) {
                $forecast = array();
                $attr = $fpart->attributes();
                $forecast['t']['min'] = (string)round(($fpart->temperature->attributes()->min)-273,15,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                $forecast['t']['min'] = $forecast['t']['min'] > 0 ? "+".$forecast['t']['min'] : $forecast['t']['min'];
                $forecast['t']['max'] = (string)round(($fpart->temperature->attributes()->max)-273,15,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                $forecast['t']['max'] = $forecast['t']['max'] > 0 ? "+".$forecast['t']['max'] : $forecast['t']['max'];
                $forecast['p']['min'] = (string)round($fpart->pressure->attributes()->value,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                // $forecast['p']['max'] = (string)$fpart->PRESSURE->attributes()->max;
                $forecast['w']['min'] = (string)round($fpart->windSpeed->attributes()->mps,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                //$forecast['w']['max'] = (string)$fpart->WIND->attributes()->max;
                //$forecast['w']['rumb'] = (string)$fpart->WIND->attributes()->direction;
                $forecast['h']['min'] = (string)$fpart->humidity->attributes()->value;
                //$forecast['h']['max'] = (string)$fpart->RELWET->attributes()->max;
                $forecast['symb'] = (string)$fpart->symbol->attributes()->name;
                $forecast['pict'] = (string)$fpart->symbol->attributes()->var;
                $date = date('c',strtotime($hoffset.' hours',strtotime($attr['from'])));
                $hour = date('H',strtotime($date));
                $forecast['timestamp'] =strtotime($date);
                $date = strtotime($date);
                $dayofweek = date('w',$date);
                $date = $weekdays[$dayofweek]." ".date('d.m',$date);
                if ($forecast['timestamp'] > time()){
                    $days[$date][$hour] = $forecast;
                }

            }
        } else {$days=array();}

    }
    return [$cityname => $days];

}

$outputData = array();
$forecast = getForecastXML();
if (count($forecast) > 0) {
    foreach ($forecast as $date => $daypart) {
        $outputData[] = $date;
        foreach ($daypart as $dp => $data) {
            $outputData[] = str_pad($dp, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $outputData[] = $data['symb'];
            $outputData[] = $data['t']['min'];
            $outputData[] = $data['t']['max'];

            if (($data['p']['min']) > 0) {
                $outputData[] = "Давление " . round($data['p']['min'] * 0.75006375541921) . "мм. рт. ст.";
            }

        }
    }
} else {
    $outputData[] = "В данный момент информация о погоде отсутствует";
}

echo implode(' ', $outputData);




//Выводим данные на сайт

/*if (count($this->forecast)>0) { foreach ($this->forecast as $date=>$daypart) :

    echo $date;

    foreach ($daypart as $dp=>$data) :

        echo str_pad($dp,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo $data['symb'];
        echo $data['t']['min'];
        echo $data['t']['max'];

    if (($data['p']['min']) > 0) :

    echo "Давление" .round($data['p']['min']*0.75006375541921). "мм. рт. ст.";

    endif;

    endforeach;

    endforeach;

    }  else {

    echo "В данный момент информация о погоде отсутствует";

}*/

?>
```

Comment: И посоветовал бы вот этот момент `return array($cityname,$days);` вернуть таким образом`return [$cityname => $days]` тогда у вас будет правильная вложенность и ваши переборы сработают.

Comment: попробовал, в итоге ничего не показывает типа NULL

Comment: Не могу через онлайн сервисы запустить код, т.к. присутствует `file_get_contents`, но вот результат с моего локального сервера `Balezino Четверг 27.06 Пятница 28.06 Суббота 29.06 Воскресенье 30.06 Понедельник 01.07 Вторник 02.07`

Comment: А что вы подправили? подскажите пожалуйста у меня никак не получается запустить

Comment: даты у меня сейчас тоже заработали. Единственное не работает это $outputData[] = $data['t']['min'];
            $outputData[] = $data['t']['max'];  не выводит результат

Comment: Поправил return в самой функции getForecastXML, теперь там возвращается массив вида `[ cityname => ['data_about_city']]` и ниже добавил вызов функции `$forecast = getForecastXML();`

Comment: По другим параметрам как подправить? не выводит ничего. выводит только дни недели. А сам прогноз пустота